Optimizing a cumulative price calculation query
I have a "pricing engine" query that is getting the cost (per source country) of a product variant, and is calculating taxes & margins in a cumulative fashion (one on top of the other and so forth ex: ((cost * tariff)*tariff) etc...) according to the order in which they need to be applied, in order to calculate the final price per channel: wholesale, b2b etc.
The query does work using recursion but it's rather heavy. I've tried to accomplish the same thing using window functions. But I just do not get the correct result at the end.
Any ideas/suggestions on how I can optimize and make it way more performant?
WITH RECURSIVE __static AS (
    SELECT NOW() AS __t_now
),
raw AS (
 SELECT
        pp.p_var_id,

        pp.r_ch_id,
        _ch.channel,

        pp.r_pl_c_id, -- source country
        _c.source_r_pl_c_id,
        _c.source_r_ccy_id,

        _c.splr_acct_id,
        _c.source_cost,

        _br.bkng_rt_id,
        _br.rate AS rate, -- default to 1 -- no rate defined

        _c.source_cost * COALESCE(_br.rate, 1) AS target_cost,
        _ch.r_ccy_id AS target_r_ccy_id,
        _pt.position,

        pp.p_pr_id,

        COALESCE(pp.p_pr_ty_id, _pc.p_pr_ty_id) AS p_pr_ty_id,
        COALESCE(pp.tariff, _pc.tariff, 0) AS tariff_normalized,
        COALESCE(pp.fixed, _pc.fixed, 0) AS fixed_normalized,

        COALESCE(pp.tariff, _pc.tariff) AS tariff,
        COALESCE(pp.fixed, _pc.fixed) AS fixed,

        ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER (
                PARTITION BY
                    pp.p_var_id,
                    pp.r_pl_c_id,
                    _c.source_cost,
                    _c.source_r_pl_c_id,
                    _c.source_r_ccy_id,
                    _c.splr_acct_id,
                    pp.r_ch_id,
                    _br.bkng_rt_id,
                    _br.rate
                ORDER BY _pt.position DESC
            ) AS row_number


    FROM prices pp
    CROSS JOIN __static

    LEFT JOIN price_components _pc on _pc.p_pr_cmp_id = pp.p_pr_cmp_id
    LEFT JOIN price_types _pt on _pt.p_pr_ty_id = COALESCE(pp.p_pr_ty_id, _pc.p_pr_ty_id)
    LEFT JOIN channels _ch ON pp.r_ch_id = _ch.r_ch_id AND _ch.active IS TRUE

    LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.p_var_id, c.splr_acct_id)
            c.p_var_id,
            c.splr_acct_id,
            c.cost AS source_cost,
            c.bkng_rt_src_id,
            c.r_ccy_id AS source_r_ccy_id,
            c.r_pl_c_id AS source_r_pl_c_id
        FROM costs c
        WHERE
            c.r_pl_c_id = pp.r_pl_c_id -- match cost source country to price source country (new)
            AND __static.__t_now BETWEEN c.t_from AND c.t_until
        ORDER BY c.p_var_id, c.splr_acct_id, c.t DESC
    ) _c ON pp.p_var_id = _c.p_var_id

    LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (br.bkng_rt_src_id, br.source_r_ccy_id, br.target_r_ccy_id)
            br.bkng_rt_id,
            br.bkng_rt_src_id,
            br.rate
        FROM rates br
        WHERE
            _c.source_r_ccy_id <> _ch.r_ccy_id  -- Only join if conversion is needed
            AND br.source_r_ccy_id = _c.source_r_ccy_id --cost source ccy
            AND br.target_r_ccy_id = _ch.r_ccy_id --channel target ccy
            AND br.bkng_rt_src_id = _c.bkng_rt_src_id
            AND __static.__t_now >= br.t_from
            AND br.deleted IS FALSE

        ORDER BY br.bkng_rt_src_id, br.source_r_ccy_id, br.target_r_ccy_id, br.t_from DESC
    ) _br ON _c.bkng_rt_src_id = _br.bkng_rt_src_id

    WHERE __static.__t_now BETWEEN pp.t_from AND pp.t_until
    GROUP BY
        __static.__t_now,
        _c.p_var_id, _c.source_cost,
        pp.r_pl_c_id, _c.source_r_pl_c_id,
        _c.source_r_ccy_id, _c.splr_acct_id, _ch.r_ccy_id,
        pp.p_var_id, pp.r_ch_id,
        _ch.r_ch_id, _ch.channel, _br.bkng_rt_id, _br.rate,
        _pt.position,
        pp.p_pr_ty_id, _pc.p_pr_ty_id,
        pp.p_pr_id,
        pp.tariff, _pc.tariff,
        pp.fixed, _pc.fixed
),
calc AS (
    SELECT *,

        target_cost + (target_cost * tariff_normalized) + fixed_normalized AS cumulative, -- Apply first tariff

        jsonb_build_array(
            jsonb_build_object(
                'p_pr_id', p_pr_id,
                'p_pr_ty_id', p_pr_ty_id,
                'tariff', trim_scale(tariff),
                'fixed', trim_scale(fixed),
                'subtotal', trim_scale((target_cost * tariff_normalized) + fixed_normalized)
            )
        ) AS components

    FROM raw
    WHERE row_number = 1  -- Start with the highest position tariff

    UNION ALL

    SELECT raw.*,

        cc.cumulative + (cc.cumulative * raw.tariff_normalized) + raw.fixed_normalized AS cumulative, -- Apply each subsequent tariff

        cc.components ||  jsonb_build_object(
            'p_pr_id', raw.p_pr_id,
            'p_pr_ty_id', raw.p_pr_ty_id,
            'tariff', trim_scale(raw.tariff),
            'fixed', trim_scale(raw.fixed),
            'subtotal', trim_scale((cc.cumulative * raw.tariff_normalized) + raw.fixed_normalized)
        ) AS components

    FROM calc cc
    JOIN raw ON
        cc.p_var_id = raw.p_var_id
        AND cc.r_pl_c_id = raw.r_pl_c_id
        AND cc.source_cost = raw.source_cost
        AND cc.source_r_pl_c_id = raw.source_r_pl_c_id
        AND cc.source_r_ccy_id = raw.source_r_ccy_id
        AND cc.splr_acct_id IS NOT DISTINCT FROM raw.splr_acct_id
        AND cc.r_ch_id = raw.r_ch_id
        AND cc.bkng_rt_id IS NOT DISTINCT FROM raw.bkng_rt_id
        AND cc.rate IS NOT DISTINCT FROM raw.rate
        AND cc.row_number + 1 = raw.row_number  -- Join on the next lower tariff
)

SELECT *
FROM calc c
WHERE row_number = (
    SELECT MAX(raw.row_number)
    FROM raw
    WHERE
        p_var_id = c.p_var_id
        AND r_pl_c_id = c.r_pl_c_id
        AND source_cost = c.source_cost
        AND source_r_pl_c_id = c.source_r_pl_c_id
        AND source_r_ccy_id = c.source_r_ccy_id
        AND splr_acct_id IS NOT DISTINCT FROM c.splr_acct_id
        AND r_ch_id = c.r_ch_id
        AND bkng_rt_id IS NOT DISTINCT FROM c.bkng_rt_id
        AND rate IS NOT DISTINCT FROM c.rate
    )
;

Please find a live version here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vnM3o5RZnhvyNgSqr57w66/0
PS. This is meant to go into a materialized view (thats why it's calculating everything). But I would still like to optimize the heck out of it, because I will need to readapt it in order to get the price for a single product.

Correct result:
+--------+-------+--------+---------+----------------+---------------+------------+-----------+----------+---------+-----------+---------------+--------+-------+----------+-----------------+----------------+------+-----+----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|p_var_id|r_ch_id|r_pl_c_id|source_r_pl_c_id|source_r_ccy_id|splr_acct_id|source_cost|bkng_rt_id|rate     |target_cost|target_r_ccy_id|position|p_pr_id|p_pr_ty_id|tariff_normalized|fixed_normalized|tariff|fixed|row_number|cumulative   |components                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
+--------+-------+--------+---------+----------------+---------------+------------+-----------+----------+---------+-----------+---------------+--------+-------+----------+-----------------+----------------+------+-----+----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1       |4      |807      |807             |978            |1           |100.000000 |null      |null     |100        |978            |70      |33     |4         |0.35             |0               |0.3500|null |2         |152.55       |[{"fixed": null, "tariff": 0.13, "p_pr_id": 34, "subtotal": 13, "p_pr_ty_id": 2}, {"fixed": null, "tariff": 0.35, "p_pr_id": 33, "subtotal": 39.55, "p_pr_ty_id": 4}]                                                                                                                                                                                       |
|1       |4      |807      |807             |807            |null        |2000.000000|6         |0.016129 |32.258     |978            |70      |33     |4         |0.35             |0               |0.3500|null |2         |49.209579    |[{"fixed": null, "tariff": 0.13, "p_pr_id": 34, "subtotal": 4.19354, "p_pr_ty_id": 2}, {"fixed": null, "tariff": 0.35, "p_pr_id": 33, "subtotal": 12.758039, "p_pr_ty_id": 4}]                                                                                                                                                                              |
|1       |1      |807      |807             |978            |1           |100.000000 |1         |61.696400|6169.64    |807            |1       |19     |1         |0.18             |0               |0.1800|null |4         |11110.0372676|[{"fixed": null, "tariff": 0.13, "p_pr_id": 28, "subtotal": 802.0532, "p_pr_ty_id": 2}, {"fixed": null, "tariff": 0.35, "p_pr_id": 26, "subtotal": 2440.09262, "p_pr_ty_id": 4}, {"fixed": 3.5, "tariff": null, "p_pr_id": 27, "subtotal": 3.5, "p_pr_ty_id": 3}, {"fixed": null, "tariff": 0.18, "p_pr_id": 19, "subtotal": 1694.7514476, "p_pr_ty_id": 1}]|
|1       |2      |807      |807             |978            |1           |100.000000 |1         |61.696400|6169.64    |807            |1       |31     |1         |0.18             |0               |0.1800|null |4         |11932.6970652|[{"fixed": null, "tariff": 0.13, "p_pr_id": 32, "subtotal": 802.0532, "p_pr_ty_id": 2}, {"fixed": null, "tariff": 0.45, "p_pr_id": 29, "subtotal": 3137.26194, "p_pr_ty_id": 4}, {"fixed": 3.5, "tariff": null, "p_pr_id": 30, "subtotal": 3.5, "p_pr_ty_id": 3}, {"fixed": null, "tariff": 0.18, "p_pr_id": 31, "subtotal": 1820.2419252, "p_pr_ty_id": 1}]|
|1       |1      |807      |807             |807            |null        |2000.000000|null      |null     |2000       |807            |1       |19     |1         |0.18             |0               |0.1800|null |4         |3604.31      |[{"fixed": null, "tariff": 0.13, "p_pr_id": 28, "subtotal": 260, "p_pr_ty_id": 2}, {"fixed": null, "tariff": 0.35, "p_pr_id": 26, "subtotal": 791, "p_pr_ty_id": 4}, {"fixed": 3.5, "tariff": null, "p_pr_id": 27, "subtotal": 3.5, "p_pr_ty_id": 3}, {"fixed": null, "tariff": 0.18, "p_pr_id": 19, "subtotal": 549.81, "p_pr_ty_id": 1}]                  |
|1       |2      |807      |807             |807            |null        |2000.000000|null      |null     |2000       |807            |1       |31     |1         |0.18             |0               |0.1800|null |4         |3870.99      |[{"fixed": null, "tariff": 0.13, "p_pr_id": 32, "subtotal": 260, "p_pr_ty_id": 2}, {"fixed": null, "tariff": 0.45, "p_pr_id": 29, "subtotal": 1017, "p_pr_ty_id": 4}, {"fixed": 3.5, "tariff": null, "p_pr_id": 30, "subtotal": 3.5, "p_pr_ty_id": 3}, {"fixed": null, "tariff": 0.18, "p_pr_id": 31, "subtotal": 590.49, "p_pr_ty_id": 1}]                 |
+--------+-------+--------+---------+----------------+---------------+------------+-----------+----------+---------+-----------+---------------+--------+-------+----------+-----------------+----------------+------+-----+----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


Table definitions (foreign keys and identity removed):
create table if not exists rate_sources
(
    bkng_rt_src_id serial,
    hidden         boolean default false not null,
    active         boolean default false not null,
    position       integer,
    bkng_bnk_id    integer,
    ent_acct_id    integer,
    r_pl_c_id      integer,
    name           jsonb
);
        
create table if not exists rates
(
    bkng_rt_id      serial,
    t               timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)                     not null,
    deleted         boolean   default false                                    not null,
    by_e_usr_id     integer                                                    not null,
    bkng_rt_src_id  integer                                                    not null,
    t_from          timestamp default '-infinity'::timestamp without time zone not null,
    source_r_ccy_id integer,
    target_r_ccy_id integer,
    rate            numeric(14, 6)                                             not null
);

create table if not exists costs
(
    p_cst_id       serial,
    t              timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)                     not null,
    by_e_usr_id    integer                                                    not null,
    p_var_id       integer                                                    not null,
    r_pl_c_id      integer                                                    not null,
    splr_acct_id   integer,
    r_ccy_id       integer                                                    not null,
    bkng_rt_src_id integer,
    cost           numeric(14, 6)                                             not null,
    t_from         timestamp default '-infinity'::timestamp without time zone not null,
    t_until        timestamp default 'infinity'::timestamp without time zone  not null
);

create table if not exists price_components
(
    p_pr_cmp_id serial,
    hidden      boolean default false not null,
    p_pr_ty_id  integer               not null,
    r_pl_c_id   integer               not null,
    tariff      numeric(7, 4),
    fixed       numeric(14, 6)
);

create table if not exists price_types
(
    p_pr_ty_id  serial,
    hidden      boolean default false not null,
    position    integer,
    name        jsonb                 not null,
    r_pl_c_id   integer
);
  
create table if not exists channels
(
    r_ch_id   serial,
    hidden    boolean default false not null,
    active    boolean default false not null,
    position  integer,
    r_pl_c_id integer               not null,
    r_ccy_id  integer               not null,
    channel   varchar               not null,
    name      jsonb                 not null
);

create table if not exists prices
(
    p_pr_id     serial,
    t           timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
    e_usr_id    integer                             not null,
    p_var_id    integer                             not null,
    r_ch_id     integer                             not null,
    p_pr_ty_id  integer,
    p_pr_cmp_id integer,
    tariff      numeric(7, 4),
    fixed       numeric(14, 6),
    t_from      date      default '-infinity'::date not null,
    t_until     date      default 'infinity'::date  not null,
    r_pl_c_id   integer
);


Query planner output: https://codefile.io/f/MHC9ZVhb91

Please post complete table definitions (ddl) and results of explain (analyze, buffers). All as formatted text - no images - and keep the indentation for the explain plan.

@Belayer I posted the table definitions. However the query plan is way too long to post it in the main question or as a comment. Heres a link of the query planner output: https://codefile.io/f/MHC9ZVhb91

Table DDL should include foreign keys and indexes. Failure to provide complete DDL hinders the efforts of others to provide help.
